# Prove bases are orthonormal

Tags: quantum-computing

How are the bases 1/sqrt(2)*(1, i) and 1/sqrt(2)*(1, -i) orthonormal? I know for a basis to be orthonormal it must have a dot product of zero and a norm of 1. Yet, while the dot product of these two vectors is 1, my textbook lists these bases as orthonormal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Dot product here is <1|2>, which means you have to conjugate one state.

After conjugation it would be proportional to (1+i<sup>2</sup>) = 0